# Loading a separate file's code from a div into itself

Tags: jquery, load

I have modified my code which is now working but still needs to be improved:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="home" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Loader</title>

</head>

<body>

<h1>This is the default page</h1>
<div id="container">
        <img src="images/page-01.png" alt="step-01" usemap="#map-01"/>           
        <map id="map-01" name="map-01"  href="pages/next.html"  >
        <area shape="rect" coords="54,440,440,473" alt="diagram" title="diagram" href="pages/next.html"  target="_self"  />
   </map>
</div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
$('map').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#container").load($(this).attr('href')+ " #step-02");
  });

  });
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Example code for the pages/next.html file:

```
<div  id="step-02" style="background:red;">
<img src="images/page-02.png" width="465" height="838" alt="Filter" usemap="#map-02"/>
INSIDE STEP 2

                    <map id="map-02" name="map-02" href="pages/page-03.html">
                        <area  shape="rect" coords="22,107,439,171" alt="diagram" title="diagram" target="_self" href="http://www.image-maps.com/"     />
                    </map>


                    </div>

<div  id="step-03" style="background:blue;">
<img src="images/page-03.png" etc...
```

The script functions but it is not efficient. Every time a new div containing the map is loaded i.e. step-03 inside container it needs to call the following so:

```
   $("#container").load($(this).attr('href')+ " #step-02");
```

Needs to be something along the lines of

```
   $("#container").load($(this).attr('href')+ " #step[suffixidentifier]++");
```

But I do not know enough about Jquery syntax to apply this. Could anyone help?

### How To call the function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('map').click(function(){
  NextStep();
 });
});
  var step = 1;


//Later in your function
function NextStep(){
var myStep = String(step).length === 1 ? '0' + step : String(step);
$("#container").load($(this).attr('href')+ " #step-" + myStep);
step++;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space :

```
$("#step-01").load($(this).attr("href") + " #step-02"); //Between " and #
```

---

## Edit

You could go for a script like that :

```
//Declare a global var
var step = 1;


//Later in your function
function xxx(){
    var myStep = String(step).length === 1 ? '0' + step : String(step);
    $("#container").load($(this).attr('href')+ " #step-" + myStep);
    step++;
}
```

---

## Edit 2

You'll probably need event delegation since you load map every click :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var step = 1;
    $('#container').on('click', 'map', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var myStep = String(step).length === 1 ? '0' + step : String(step);
        $("#container").load($(this).attr('href')+ " #step-" + myStep);
        step++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Karl, I had a few bugs getting it to work but if you look at my code above, I have now edited it but found a few flaws. How do I make the code more efficient?

Comment: THanks Karl. Stupid question as I am a beginner, how do I call the function from the map element? My syntax is pretty poor, do I need to declare the document.ready handler?

Comment: I edited the code again trying to call the function as you can see above but I am confused about JQuery's syntax and logic so it is not working.

Comment: @Cigana there is no stupid question, try my last edit!

Comment: Thanks for your help Karl, unfortunately nothing is happening. I pasted your EDIT 2 to replace the existing jquery code, but unfortunately, it only loads the page URL if I click on the map. Could it be anything to do on how the #step-01 and #step-02 etc. Have a 0 before the number?

Comment: Try preventing default behavior : `function(e){ e.preventDefault()...`. Im talking about the function inside the `.on()`.

Comment: I will have to try to understand what you mean when I get home as I do not know where to add this. I put it here: function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
        var myStep = String(step).length === 1 ? '0' + step : String(step); but it does not work.

Comment: @Cigana That was the right spot, but if it didn't work, i don't know what's the problem, you should run a series of test like what is the var `myStep` to know if the string is right... Maybe you should start on `step = 2` instead of one....

Comment: Thanks Karl. I had to go with a different solution as this was giving me a lot of unnecessary headache. I will see if I can play with this when I get a chance.